# React Native Webview menuItems prop cannot use on iOS >= 16

Tags: objective-c, react-native, uikit

I'm using React Native with the `react-native-webview` library. My code is like this:

```
<SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
      <WebView
          useWebKit={true}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          hideKeyboardAccessoryView={true}
          keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction={false}
          nestedScrollEnabled={!useContainer}
          style={[styles.webview, style]}
          {...rest}
          menuItems={[{ key: 'test0001', label: 'Bold Test' }]}
          onCustomMenuSelection={(event) => {
            console.log('hehehe');
          }}
      />
</SafeAreaView>
```

It's work well with iOS <= 15, but cannot run on iOS >= 16. I figured out the reason is UIMenuController has been deprecated and we should use UIEditMenuInteraction instead.

Any suggestion or document/links for me? Please help me, thank you so much.

P/s: I tried to edit the library native code but it seems Objective-C is so strange to me :(((